# how to get already done projects in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am new to blackberry... I need an idea how to search already existing projects in blackberry..... please anyone help me....

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean codes???? 
Google it

Do you mean running applications only???
Find them in `Blackberry App Store` , there are many sites who has the cod files available but this is a common repository.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I don't just post links that are the first link in google but I thought this time I would.

The blackberry website is filled with sample applications http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=Sample+Applications